# why does nutch always create the linkdb, even though it's not need for content fetching?

Tags: nutch

I am reading thru the chapter on nutch in hadoop, the definitive guide. I understand the concept of ranking a page using inverse link. However, I don't see that playing a role when you just want to crawl a few sites. Since creation of the linkdb is a map reduce job, it's bound to take up a lot of computing resources. I am just wondering why is linkdb always generated when most of nutch use cases is just getting web content for designated urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because Nutch uses the page rank (which is being calculated using link information) to prioritize crawling. For instance, a link that has a high page rank will be crawled before than the one with low page rank.

Nutch was designed to be used as a large scale web crawler,therefore calculating page rank and scoring web pages with it was and still an important component. If you are crawling a few sites, then you probably should use scrappy (a python library).

I hope  that answers your question.

Comment: In practical terms, are you saying some people are anxiously waiting for each scraped page, so that higher priority make that much difference. Because, whatever the priority, all the pages will eventually get crawled, right?

Comment: @user1058511 When you want to crawl at web scale, the crawling process may takes too much. Therefore you need to crawl websites with higher frequency of update sooner, unless you will miss some changes of web.

Comment: I never thought from that angel before.